# Coverage "No source for code" with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py

I am trying to measure code coverage by my **pytest** tests. I tried following the quick start guide of coverage (https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4.1/)

When I run my test with the following command, everything seems fine

```
coverage run -m pytest tests/
```

```
===================================== test session starts ======================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/arnaud/Documents/Github/gotcha
collected 4 items                                                                              

tests/preprocessing/test_preprocessing.py ....                                           [100%]

====================================== 4 passed in 0.30s =======================================
```

However, when I try to access the report with either of those commands,

```
coverage report

coverage html
```

I get the following message:

```
No source for code: '<project_directory>/config-3.py'.
```

I did not find an appropriate solution to this problem so far

Comment: This might be related to using OpenCV, see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/77336802/4742780.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to ignore errors using the command

```
coverage html -i
```

which solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to specify the `source` attribute. In my case, rather than the whole project (`source = .`), I specified the actual source folder (e.g. `src`). This can either be done on the commandline:

```bash
coverage run --source=src
```

or include it in your `.coveragerc` file:

```bash
[run]
source = src
...
```

I was getting this same issue because of a specific library I was importing*, but I never figured out why that library affected coverage, and others didn't.

Though this might just be a workaround, it makes sense to just check your source folder, and ignoring all errors (with `-i`) isn't much better.

* The library uses `opencv-python-headless`, which I think has the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is usually caused by older coverage result files, so you can either:

- remove the old coverage results files or...
- run coverage command with `-i` flag in order to ignore the errors - you can read more about that in coverage official docs: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4.1/cmd.html#reporting

Answer (score 2):

This is related to https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1653

A temporary solution is to explicitly omit the `opencv-python` synthetic files that are created at install time.

Add this to your `.coveragerc` file (or any other configuration file you're using):

```
omit = 
    config.py
    config-3.py
```